# android.widget.SearchView not updating with attributes defined in sytle.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, searchview, android-styles

I am trying to set cursor/hint/icon color of my SearchView in white. Defined the style for it but SearchView is not updating it is showing in black. Kindly suggest what is missing in my code.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar" >
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/color_white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/color_white</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/color_white</item>
    <item name="queryHint">@string/search_hint</item>
</style>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<color name="color_white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

SearchView defined in a layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<-- other views code -->

<SearchView
    style="@style/SearchViewStyle"
    android:id="@+id/header_search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

UI on phone screen:

[image]

Comment: Is that style screen-specific or global for the whole app?

Comment: It is screen-specific

Answer (score 0):

Use `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` and not `SearchView`.

`SearchView` doesn't know what `"Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar"` means.